# LinkedList, struct inclusion issue

Tags: c, list, struct, header, linked-list

```
liststructs.h:

struct _data_object {
    int temp;
int interval_length;
}; 
typedef struct _data_object temp_data_object;

struct _list_node {
data_object *temp_data;
struct _list_node *prev;
struct _list_node *next;
}; 
typedef struct _list_node list_node;

struct _list {
int time;
list_node *head;
list_node *tail;
};
typedef struct _list list;


list.h:
list_node *alloc_node(int temp, int interval_length);
list_node *alloc_dummy_node(void);
list *alloc_temp_list(void);
void delete_first(list *list);
void insert_node(list *list, list_node *new_node);
void insert(list *list, int temperature, int interval);
```

I then use this in another file called `calculations.c` and in `main.c`, but then I declare `extern list *xs;` in `calculations.h` (it is defined in `calculations.c`) it complains:
`Error[Pe020]: identifier "list" is undefined`

I have included `liststructs.h` and `list.h` in that order in `calculations.c` and `main.c` and want to use `xs` in `calculations` and `main`.

Also:
What is better? To have structs and listoperations declared in the same header or separate them?

Comment: Are you including `liststructs.h` in `calculations.h` before you're using the identifier `list`?

Answer (score 0):

Protect your include files with `#include` safeguards, include `liststructs.h` in `list.h`, and both files in `calculations.h`. Safeguards in header files are typically written as:

```
#ifndef _XXXX_H_ // XXXX = LIST, LISTSTRUCT etc
#define _XXXX_H_

// definitions for file XXXX.h

#endif /* _XXXX_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told us, you have `extern list *xs;` declared in `calculations.h`, but didn't mention having included `liststructs.h` before that line which defines the identifier `list`.

`liststructs.h` needs to be included anywhere before you use the identifier `list`, just as `list.h` must be included before you attempt to call any of the functions it declares.

As long as you have [include/header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) don't worry about including header files multiple times in a translation unit.

Comment: Should I include the liststructs.h file in calculations.h ? Seems wrong. When I try I get: Error[Pe513]: a value of type "struct _list *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "list *" and more of the same error.

Comment: @user1106072: You wouldn't "need" to if `liststructs.h` was included before `calculations.h` in `main`, but I'd stick the `#include` in `calculations.h`. It's hard to tell why the error's happening without seeing the actual files and how you're compiling them.